# How to use interceptor in Python Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm in need of a interceptor concept in pyramid for checking whether session is available or not on every view method call. Is it possible to do that? I know that in Java Struts there is a concept called Login Interceptor which does the same. Is there any login interceptor concept in pyramid?

Comment: tweens will probably work for this. http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/hooks.html#registering-tweens they are like wsgi middleware but have additional benefit of having access to the application registry, the docs are pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

What Tom Willis suggests is one option, but I think what you really are looking for is event system:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/narr/events.html

You can subscribe to NewRequest to perform something based on the fact session/user us present or not.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.5-branch/api/events.html#pyramid.events.NewRequest